# with that or without, the most formal way

Tags: grammaticality, grammar

I have this sentence

> There is an engine inside me **that** keeps saying "someone must be at the top, why isn't that you?"

Should I put *that* or not?

I know both ways are correct, but I am asking for the most formal way.